# rouble with mounting Python code to FUSE: No response and prolonged processing ---

Tags: filesystems, mount, fuse, entropy

I attempted to mount my Python code to FUSE using the command `python3 entropyfs.py ~/root ~/mount_point`. However, the command doesn't seem to be functioning as expected. Instead of mounting the filesystem and providing the desired FUSE filesystem for entropy calculation, the command stops responding and remains stuck in a processing state for hours without any visible progress.

What could be the possible reasons for this issue? How can I troubleshoot and resolve it effectively to achieve successful mounting of my Python code to FUSE?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: To debug: First, run the command under _strace_: `strace python3 entropyfs.py ...`. Second, enable "debug" in your fuse file system. Either with mount flag "debug" or in the arguments to the code function that mounts fuse.